# Why is there a 4 hour wait after reviewing 20 first posts?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, rate-limiting

As you can see from my rep, I recently received the privilege of reviewing first posts. While I was doing this today, I (apparently) reviewed my 20th post and was told to wait 4 hours before reviewing any more.

Why the wait period? Reviewing doesn't directly give rep (unless you edit the question, which I found I have done only a few times), so it doesn't seem like abuse would be easy, and for the most part is just a way to give back to the community (if done properly).

I'm curious as to the reasons behind this wait period.

Comment: It's not a "4 hour wait period". You can review 20 per day. The day just happens to roll over to a new one in 4 hours.

Answer (score 11):

You'd think that there'd be no incentive to abuse the queue, but you'd be wrong.  There are an *enormous* number of people that have been abusing the queue (mostly in the form of rubber stamping everything, or most everything, without actually paying attention to what's in the post).

Comment: I guess I just don't see the point in it. Maybe to get a badge? It's not like spam editing posts that have the potential for +2 rep.

Comment: Yes, to get badges. There are bronze, silver, and gold badges awarded for reviewing 1 item, 250 items, and 1000 items in each queue.

Comment: And while it is nice to get an imaginary badge for helping to keep the site clean, yes, it is silly to abuse the system for that imaginary badge. But people do it.