# Why do I need to wait 20 hours after reviewing only 20 questions?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I put my daughter to bed. My wife is on Kindle mode. Woow! My s/o reviewing time.
I can spend like 1 hour/day reading first posts to check their quality. I can do 20 triages in Max 30 minutes. Why can't I devote more of my time to such task?
I know there's a real need of limiting this, in order to evenly distribute reviews among users.
My discussion shot is: **why 20**?

Comment: Well, there is also First Posts, Late Answers, and once you have more rep, there are 7 other queues, for a total of 160 reviews per day !

Comment: And [Why is there a 4 hour wait after reviewing 20 first posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262170/62576) has some more information.